# How to calculate effective branching factor?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I would like to calculate the ***effective branching factor*** of a tree in order to assess the quality of my heuristic in A* search.

The post [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35665/can-the-effective-branching-factor-be-negative) offer a very good explanation of the formula :
N+1=1+B∗+(B∗)^2+⋯+(B∗)^d, presented in the [AI: A Modern Approach](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/) (by Stuart Russell and Peter Norvig) book. Where, N is the number of nodes searched and the solution depth is
d and "b* is the branching factor that a uniform tree of depth d would have to have in order
to contain N +1 nodes"

I am really puzzled with the example presented in the book. They say:

> For example, if A* finds a solution at depth 5 using 52 nodes, then
> the effective branching factor is 1.92.

How did they come up with this value? As explained [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35665/can-the-effective-branching-factor-be-negative) an approximation to this formula is given by B∗≈N^(1/d).

Using that formula with values in the example from the book I get 2.20 = 52 ^ (1/5), which is a bit far off the value presented in the book as a solution (which btw is not said to be an approximation).

So, my question is how did they come up with the value 1.92? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approximation of `N+1 = 1+B∗+(B∗)^2+⋯+(B∗)^d` by the equation `B∗ ≈ N^(1/d)` is only accurate for larger values of `B∗`. The true formula is `((B∗)^(d+1) - 1) / (B∗ - 1) = N+1`. When `B∗` is not significantly larger than `1`, the error of the approximation can be very high.

If you solve for `B∗` in the equation `53 = ((B∗)^(d+1) - 1) / (B∗ - 1)`, for example using [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) or another numerical solver, the true value (to 6 s.f.) is `B∗ ≈ 1.916729`, or `B∗ ≈ 1.92` in the textbook.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. Could you please elaborate a bit more on how you do you get to the formula ((B∗)^(d+1) - 1) / (B∗ - 1) = N+1.

Comment: @jcampos Absolutely; that's the closed form solution of a [geometric series.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula) So `((B∗)^(d+1) - 1) / (B∗ - 1)` is the partial sum of the geometric series with ratio `B*`. The original formula was `1+B∗+(B∗)^2+⋯+(B∗)^d`.